# Load csv file into SnowFlake table using python

Tags: python, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to upload csv files from Python into Snowflake.

Here is my code:

```
drop stage if exists "SCHEMA"."DATABASE".data_stage

create stage "SCHEMA"."DATABASE".data_stage file_format = (type = "csv" field_delimiter = "," skip_header = 1)

put file://C://Users//318459//Downloads//Student_marks.csv @DATA_STAGE auto_compress=true
```

I dont have access to other ways to upload the files into my snowflake server,

I already connected python and I can create sql scripts, but show me an error with the last line "put file". Any idea? I tried to run this directly into snowflake and this is the error.

ERROR:

> SQL compilation error: The command is not supported from the UI: PUT

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`put` command cannot be used in UI as the error message states, you can use it within python though.

Also, you don't need to create a stage for this purpose, you can either use user or table stages. They are stages already exist, for more info :
[Types of Stages](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-create-stage.html#choosing-a-stage-for-local-files)

Comment: Hi, I used this code http://deltafrog.com/load-csv-file-into-snowflake-table-using-python/   created the table as well but never inserted the data and didn't show me an error, what could be?

Comment: Looked at the link, not a good example to follow. Check with Snowflake History tab to see if put and copy into commands successfully.